# Dataframe doesn't modify in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, copy

I have this for loop and I would like to change the value of a part of a df.

```
for col in last_df:
    last_df.loc[last_df[col]!=0, col]='stop'
    stop=last_df[last_df[col]=='stop'][col].index[0]
    last_df[col].loc[:(stop-1)]='NaN'
```

At the end, the last_df doesn't modify, the error I receive is the following:
`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame See the caveats in the documentation:....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without the loc.

```
for col in last_df:
        last_df[last_df[col]!=0]='stop'
        stop=last_df[last_df[col]=='stop'][col].index[0]
        last_df[col][:(stop-1)]='NaN'
```

this is a issue with view and copy of the DataFrame for more information quick understand you can read in this [link](https://www.skytowner.com/explore/difference_between_copy_and_view_in_pandas)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: what exactly not working? it's still doesn't modify? @MattiaBolognesi

Comment: try to fix the second row to be like this:         `last_df[last_df[col]!=0]='stop'` @MattiaBolognesi

Comment: It's still not modifying the cell :(

Comment: Can you send an example of the df ? How does it looks? @MattiaBolognesi

Comment: Thanks man, now it's working :)